# Mongoose populate multiple nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've searched high and low but can't figure out how to form the following populate query, first here are my models:

```
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
    classes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Classroom' }]
});

const ClassSchema = new Schema({
    location: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location' },
    instructors: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});
```

I have an endpoint which gets a single course, but I want to populate the `classes` field AND the `location` and `instructors` fields in `classes`. Right now, I can either populate the instructors field in `classes` or `location`, but I can't populate both of them at the same time. This is what I have for now:

```
    Course
        .findById(req.params.courseId)
        .populate({
            path: 'classes',
            populate: {
                path: 'instructors',
                model: 'User'
            }
        })
```

How can I also populate the `location` field in `classes`?

Thanks.

Comment: use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate

Comment: I wonder if this works: `.populate({ path : 'classes', populate : { path : 'instructors location' } })`.

Comment: @robertklep, I test your code, only the `location` is populated correctly. however, the `instructors` is empty, it is not populated...

Comment: @zangw too bad :-( I was hoping that the multiple population option (space-separated field names) would work in this situation too.

Comment: @robertklep, yes, I was thinking the same way as before. However, it does not work well...

Comment: @zangw how about this: `.populate({ path : 'classes', populate : 'instructors location' })`?

Comment: @robertklep, It does not work either, only the `ObjectId` of `instructors` and `location` are retrieved, not populated to the real data...

Comment: @zangw thanks for checking! =D

Answer (score 77, accepted):

An interest alternative is pass an array to nested populate.

```
Course
    .findById(req.params.courseId)
    .populate({
        path: 'classes',
        model: 'Classroom',
        populate: [{
            path: 'instructors',
            model: 'User'
        },
        {
            path: 'location',
            model: 'Location'
        }]
    })
```

Comment: What if inside that array of populates we would need to add one more populate. Is that possible?

Comment: Awesome! works like charm! this is what i needed. thank you

Comment: Sweet answer. Thanks.

Comment: I saw answer and thought it is amazing. I was gonna UP it but I saw I alredy "UP"'ed it. We people are really so forgetful : )

Answer (score 13):

Please try this one under mongoose v4, here is one good link about [`Population`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#improved-population-support-for-arrays-within-arrays)

```
   Course
        .findById(req.params.courseId)
        .populate({
            path: 'classes',
            model: 'Classroom',
            populate: {
                path: 'instructors',
                model: 'User'           
            }
        })
        .exec(function(err, cour) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else {
                Course.populate(cour, 
                    {
                        path: 'classes.location',
                        model: 'Location',
                    }, function(err, c1) {
                        if (err)
                            console.log(err);
                        else
                            console.log(util.inspect(c1, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));                       
                    })
            }
        })
```

Comment: Using the deep-populate plugin works, but I tried your answer and it only populates the instructors field, the location field returns only as an id.

Answer (score 5):

```
Try the below code    


getAllByQuery: function (query, callback) {
    this
      .find(query, {capId: 1})
      .populate({path: 'capId',
        model: 'cap',
        select: {
          'capDetail': 0,
          'area': 0,
        },
        populate: [{
          path: 'ad_Id',
          model: 'Ad',
          select: { 'Level': 1}
        },
        {
          path: 'ctgs',
          model: 'Ctgry',
          select: { '_id': 0}
        }]
      })
      .exec(callback);
  }
```